# Problem with Navbar Bootstrap on mobile view

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a problem with a navbar from Bootstrap. I don't understand why but when I put this webpage on mobile view the Bootstrap Navbar collapse doesn't show when i click on the button on the right ...
Here is my code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>SmartHorse | Accueil</title>
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f7131c55f8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

        <img src="Logo_V2.jpeg" alt="cheval" class="nav-logo image-logo">
        <button class="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Accueil</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="blockchain.html">La technologie blockchain</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" style="background-color: white; height: 23px; width: 23px; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 8px">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/smarthorse/"><img src="https://www.makrea.com/img_pngs/RS03.png" alt="logo linkedin" style="width: 25px; padding-bottom: 5px"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: Weird the demo works and create a html file and opened it locally with your code in mobile mode in the dev console and also works. https://imgur.com/a/LtphFZ1

Comment: Yeah i couldn't copy and paste the whole code in can you copy this link in your IDE please ? https://github.com/Obskurcyte/SmartHorse.git (there is the full code of the page and I think the problem doesn't come from my nav but from the rest of the code itself)

Comment: The problem seems to be come from the css which is strange but when I commented the lines of my css it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys !
The problem came from my CSS I put the property (position: absolute left 74%) to my ul hence the problem on mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code to my editor and opened the file, I don't see any issue here, works as expected. What Browser are you viewing the file on? Or perhaps you don't have a body tag? You only seem to have the closing body tag.

Tablet - https://i.stack.imgur.com/buJyA.jpg

Mobile - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhsa0.jpg

Comment: Yeah i couldn't copy and paste the whole code in can you copy this link in your IDE please ? github.com/Obskurcyte/SmartHorse.git (there is the full code of the page and I think the problem doesn't come from my nav but from the rest of the code itself)